# texture does not map the whole nurbs surface

Tags: opengl, glu, nurbs

```
glGenTextures(1, &texName[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, widthImage , widthImage, 
    0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

I try to map the texture to the nurbs surface.

```
gluBeginSurface(theNurbs);

gluNurbsSurface(theNurbs, numOfKnots, knots, numOfKnots, knots, ctrNum*3, 3, &tCtrPoint[0][0][0],order, order,GL_MAP2_TEXTURE_COORD_2);

gluNurbsSurface(theNurbs, numOfKnots2, knots2, numOfKnots2, knots2, ctrNum2*3, 3, &ctrPoint[0][0][0], order2, order2, GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3);

gluEndSurface(theNurbs);
```

The problem is that the texture looks mapping all the area of the surface, however, the photo only appears in the **lower left small grid**(white grid). The other part is black.

I want to map the photo to the whole surface. But I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: So you actually post an image, but instead of the image showing the incorrect texturing, it just shows a 15*15 grid, which surely nobody has problems to imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending many hours, I finally find the problem.

When I calculate the coordinates of the control points, I use code like `tCtrPoint[i][j][1] =j/(num-1);` The problem is that the dividend and divisor are integer types. So the division`\` did not get the correct value.  I made this type of mistake before.